# How can I implement these functions into a togglebutton ? Can't get this to work

Tags: flutter, dart

Sorry, I'm relatively new to Flutter and having some trouble. I want to initiate functions when I press my first, second, or third button. These buttons initiate map markers, polylines, etc. They work fine when assigned onPress with an icon button... I can't figure out how to get them to work with a ToggleButton... Do they have to be added to a list somehow? If so, how?

Here are my three buttons:

```
            Consumer<ProviderMaps>(builder: (context, menu, widget) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1.0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                ),
                child: ToggleButtons(
                  selectedColor: Colors.red,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(MdiIcons.vectorPolygon),
                    Icon(MdiIcons.ruler),
                    Icon(MdiIcons.pencil),
                  ],
                  onPressed: (int index) {
                    setState(() {
                      for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                          buttonIndex < _selection.length;
                          buttonIndex++) {
                        if (buttonIndex == index) {
                          _selection[buttonIndex] = !_selection[buttonIndex];
                        } else {
                          _selection[buttonIndex] = false;
                        }
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  isSelected: _selection,
                ),
              );
            }),
```

My list:

```
List<bool> _selection = List.generate(3, (_) => false);
```

I'd like to call functions like these when I switch buttons:

```
menu.changestatutpolyg();
menu.changestatupolyli();
_initFreeDraw();
```

This is how I normally call these functions (works fine):

```
        Consumer<ProviderMaps>(builder: (context, menu, widget) {
          return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(MdiIcons.ruler),
              color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
              onPressed: () {
                menu.changestatupolyli();
              });
        }),
```

Anybody know how to do this? Please advise.

Edit:

Attempt#:

```
          onPressed: (int index) {
            setState(
              () {
                switch (index) {
                  case 1:
                    {
                      menu.changestatutpolyg();
                    }
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    {
                      menu.changestatupolyli();
                    }
                    break;

                  case 3:
                    {
                      _initFreeDraw();
                    }
                    break;
                }
              },
            );
          },
          isSelected: _selection,
        ),
      );
    }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `ToggleButtons`'s `onPressed` does provide you the index of the button pressed. So, the index would be 0 if the first button is pressed, one if the second, etc.

So in your onPressed, you can check the index, and based on that call the adequate function (regular if statements work fine as well):

```
onPressed: (int index) {
  switch(index) {
    case 0: {
      callFunction1();
    }
    break;
    case 1: {
      callFunction2();
    }
    break;
    //etc.
  }
},
```

Or better, you can place the functions in an array (make sure to place them in the right order), and do something like:

```
var functions = <Function>[function1, function2, function3];
//...
//then, in the onPressed:
onPressed: (int index) {
    //call the function of that index
    functions[index]();
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite working. Editing my post to show you what I did. I don't know what to do about the isSelected: _selection,  part. I tried the array but i can't put it anywhere because I don't know how to set an array when a consumer is needed (I'd need to be able to call provmaps in my case.

Comment: case 1 is the only thing working. regardless of which button i press.

Comment: Now, case 3 is the only thing working. Doesn't matter what button I press. weird

Comment: Mmm, can you try replacing by if statements? Like `if(index == 0) { ... }`

Comment: Or use the second way. I might have made a mistake in the switch statement...

Comment: can't get the second way to work because I don't know how to call             Consumer<ProviderMaps>(builder: (context, menu, widget) { before the var functions.. Do you know how to ? If I try to put function1 as menu.something, it won't work because it can't find menu. I'm still messing with your suggestion trying to get it to work

Comment: Okay now menu.changestatutpolyg(); and menu.changestatupolyli(); work but _initFreeDraw(); does not. so weird...

Comment: Actually, my bad: index starts at 0. So your button indices are 0, 1, and 2. Not 1, 2, and 3. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: works perfectly with the first solution. No array, no biggie. Thank you!